# Why does TeamCity server stop short time after it starts

Tags: tomcat, teamcity

I use TeamCity with bundled Tomcat server. I start TeamCity server using `runAll.sh start` command. The server starts and I can access its web interface. However, within a minute or two the server stops. I checked `teamcity-server.log` but it doesn't contain any information about server stopping. How can I debug it?

Answer (score 1):

According to TC Wiki page (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/TeamCity+Server+Logs) you can run server in DEBUG mode, this should give you more verbose information in log file**s** (as there is many of log files, not only this one you mentioned).

You can also monitor/check OS logs for CPU/memory usage.